# BlueZ: Implementing custom HCI notifications

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, hci

I seem to understand it is possible to customize HCI communication with custom commands (OGF==0x3f), but I wasn't able to find specific info about how to register such commands with BlueZ stack and, in general, specifics on how to handle them.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

A bit of background (ask if more is needed):

- I have a fairly standard Yocto-based Linux installation I can control.
- BLE is provided by a Nordic nRF52832.
- Communication is via standard UART (`btattach -S 460800 -B /dev/ttyHS0`).
- Since nRF is doing also "other stuff" and should report to main SoC some non-bluetooth data over the same channel (the only channel I have between the two processors) I need to multiplex.
- It *seemed* adding custom frames is the simplest way, but I need details on how to proceed.
- I need information mainly on the host/Linux side as I have nRF side "more under control".

Comment: you misunderstand the usage of OGF == 0x3f. The OGF of 0x3F is reserved for vendor-specific commands. The chip manufacturer places his proprietary / non standard HCI commands into this address space.

Comment: @Risto: as I am completely in control of the chip providing HCI service (nRF52832) and HCI command decoding is completely done "in software", I think I qualify as "vendor", in this case. Question is how to convince BlueZ (or something else) to send and receive such "proprietary / non standard HCI commands". Did I miss something?

Comment: you replace the [Nordic Softdevice](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fug_gsg_ses%2FUG%2Fgsg%2Fsoftdevices.html)  with your own radio firmware? Then I can't teach you anything new.

Comment: @risto: No, I'm using the Zephyr-based solution. This is fully open source and I'm free to modify it, if needed. Specifically I completely replaced `main()` adding several subsystems, handling the UART connection and finally using the hci-uart example as basis. I do *not* want to mess with BLE radio settings, but this can be trapped much before that. As said: I have no problem implementing special commands "device-side" without disrupting "normal flow", What I miss is how to *call* the "special commands I define" and how to handle responses/events host-side.

Comment: @ZioByte, I'm starting to look into doing the same thing. Were you able to come up with a solution that allowed BlueZ to accept your custom/vendor HCI messages?

Comment: @Dustin: no I dropped the issue (for the time being) because of "more urgent needs" ;) ... but I will need it soon enough so I would appreciate a lot if you could keep me informed of your progress, if any. I will try to keep you in the loop, but nothing will happen till next summer, unfortunately